# error while building application Couldn't delete /output.json?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i hope you have a good day
i have this problem
when i try to build an application or when connect my phone to install app on it directly from Android Studio

[this error shown up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8e4A.png)

any help ?
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with your build. Try running Clean Project and then Rebuild Project from the build menu.

Comment: it happen with all projects , you mean rebuild a new project ?

Comment: At the top menu bar of your Android Studios IDE there an option that shows "Build". Under that option you'll see "Rebuild Project" and "Clean Project". Use those.